# How to calculate a difference in AUC (with 95% CI) between two ROC curves?

Tags: r, roc, auc

I am using the roc.test function from the pROC package (version 1.17.0.1) to compare two ROC curves. The data is paired, hence using DeLong's test. However, the function does not output a confidence interval even though I specified it in the function. See example below using the aSAH dataset.

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)

roc1 <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
roc2 <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$wfns)
roc.test(roc1, roc2, method="delong", paired=TRUE,
        alternative="two.sided", conf.level=0.95, reuse.auc=TRUE)
```

The output I get is the following:

DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves

data:  roc1 and roc2
Z = -2.209, p-value = 0.02718
alternative hypothesis: true difference in AUC is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
AUC of roc1 AUC of roc2
0.7313686   0.8236789

However, no confidence interval. Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library() calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. When I run this set of parameters using the first example of the help page I DO get a confidence interval reported. You have offered neither the print output nor a [MCVE]. Voting to close.

Comment: What version of pROC? `sessionInfo()` can be useful.

Comment: @Calimo Thank you. I am using pROC_1.17.0.1.

Comment: @IRTFM Interesting. When I run the first example of the help page, I don't get a 95% CI. Would you mind sharing the code you used?

Comment: As I said, I used your parameters: `roc.test(roc1, roc2, method=c("delong"), paired=TRUE,  alternative="two.sided", conf.level=0.95, reuse.auc=TRUE)` with the `roc1` and `roc2` being objects from the first example on the help page. The AUCs were the same as you show and just above then I see: "95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.17421442 -0.01040618"  I'm using version 1.18.0

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you! Yes - I updated pROC and it now shows confidence intervals.

Comment: So this should be closed as not reproducible.

Comment: @IRTFM It is very reproducible, especially now with the edit. I don't think it should be closed, although the answer is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [new feature in pROC 1.18.0](https://xavier.robin.name/en/blog/2021/09/06/proc-1.18.0). You should update pROC to the latest version with

```
install.packages("pROC")
```